# Php Mysql combobox asterisk PMS

Tags: php, mysql, search, where-clause

Hello guys,

I need a little help with some php and MySQL queries. I have one application made by someone from GitHub that I will like to modify a little for my needs. The aplications is a FIAS-PMS from pbxinaflash with witch you can checkin, checkout and set  wakeup call for one extension. The goal is to create a different report for extension used by office and guests. For guests is working perfectly.

The code looks like this :

```
$dbconnection = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die("Database connection failed");
    mysql_select_db($dbname) or die("data base Hotel-Rooms open failed");

         $query = "SELECT `ID`, `Desc` FROM `Rooms` ORDER BY `Desc` ASC";
         $result = mysql_query($query) or die ("Couldn't execute SQL query on Hotel-Users table.") ;
    mysql_close($dbconnection);
    echo " <SELECT ID=\"RoomsComboBox\" NAME=\"RoomsComboBox\">";
    echo "<OPTION VALUE=\"ALL\" SELECTED> ".$SecLab22." </OPTION>";
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))  {
    echo "<OPTION VALUE=\"$row[0]\">" . $row[1] . "</OPTION>";
    }
    echo "</SELECT>";
echo "</TD>" ;
echo "<TD><INPUT TYPE=\"SUBMIT\" NAME=\"SearchButton\" VALUE=\"".$SecLab21."\"></TD>\n" ;
echo "</TR>\n" ;
echo "</TABLE></div>\n";
echo "</FORM>\n";

if(isset($_POST['SearchButton'])) :


echo

 "<TABLE cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=0 width=900 border=0>\n" ;
echo "<TR><TD>Id</TD><TD>".$SecLab7."</TD><TD>".$SecLab14."</TD><TD>".$SecLab15."</TD><TD>".$SecLab17."</TD><TD>".$SecLab31."</TD><TD>".$SecLab1."</TD>" ;
    $dbconnection 

= mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die("Database connection failed");
    mysql_select_db($dbname) or die("data base Hotel-Rates open failed");

    $between = '';
    $room = '';

        $query = "SELECT * FROM `Users`";
        $RoomsComboBox = $_POST['RoomsComboBox'];

    $FROMD = $_POST['FROMD'] ;
    $FROMM = $_POST['FROMM'] ;
    $FROMY = $_POST['FROMY'] ;

    $TOD = $_POST['TOD'] ;
    $TOM = $_POST['TOM'] ;
    $TOY = $_POST['TOY'] ;

    if ($RoomsComboBox !== 'ALL') {
        $room = " `Room` = '" . $RoomsComboBox . "'";
    }

    if ($FROMD !== '' AND $FROMM !== '' AND $FROMY !== '') {
        $from = " `Checkout` >= '" . $FROMY . "-" . $FROMM . "-" . $FROMD . "'";
        if ($TOD !== '' AND $TOM !== '' AND $TOY !== '') {
            $to = " AND `Checkout` <= '" . $TOY . "-" . $TOM . "-" . $TOD . "'";
        }
    $between = $from . $to;
    }


    If ($between !== '' OR $room !== '') {
        $query = $query . " WHERE" ;
    }

    If ($between !== '' AND $room !== '') {
        $query = $query . $between . " AND" . $room;
    }

    If ($between !== '' AND $room == '') {
        $query = $query . $between;
    }

    If ($between == '' AND $room !== '') {
        $query = $query . $room;
    }

    $query = $query . " ORDER BY ID DESC";
    //printf($query);
```

What I did : 
from

```
$query = "SELECT `ID`, `Desc` FROM `Rooms` ORDER BY `Desc` ASC" ;
```

to

```
$query = "SELECT `ID`, `Desc` FROM `Rooms` WHERE `Desc` = 'Frontoffice' OR `Desc` = 'Backoffice' OR `Desc` = 'Manager' ORDER BY `Desc` ASC" ;
```

from

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `Users`";
```

to

```
$query = "SELECT `ID`, `Desc` FROM `Rooms` WHERE `Desc` = 'Frontoffice' OR `Desc` = 'Backoffice' OR `Desc` = 'Manager' ORDER BY `Desc` ASC" ;
```

Partial is working, I can see in the combobox only office extensions, i can search if i peek " all " from dropdown , but if i choose something else for exemple Frontoffice and click search the page is replaying with one error.

The date search is not working at all. 
I have to advice you guys, i don`t know php and MySQL just some very basics :)
Please can someone help me with some syntaxs ? 
Thanks a lot.

enter code here

Answer (score 0):

Your first query can be simplified:

```
$query = "SELECT `ID`, `Desc` FROM `Rooms` WHERE `Desc` IN ( 'Frontoffice', 'Backoffice', 'Manager') ORDER BY `Desc` ASC" ;
```

The second query is not shown when and how it's executed, but the it's for `Users` and and **NOT** `Rooms`, so yo can't use the same line. You need to analyze the table and adapt.

Answer (score 0):

thanks. You are right it was my mistake at the second query i tried also with :

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `Users` WHERE `Desc` = 'Frontoffice' OR `Desc` = 'Backoffice' OR `Desc` = 'Manager' " ;
```

With the same result. I cannot search from checkout date, the site is displaying a query error.

Answer (score 0):

By mistake i miss the last part of code.

```
$query = $query . " ORDER BY ID DESC";
    //printf($query);

    $result = mysql_query($query) or die("Web site query failed");
    mysql_close($dbconnection);
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<TR><TD><FONT face=verdana,sans-serif>" . $row["ID"] . "</TD><TD>" . $row["Desc"]  . "</TD><TD>" .$row["Name"] ."</TD><TD>" . $row["Checkin"] . "</TD><TD>" . $row["Checkout"] . "</TD><TD>" . $row["Total"] . "</TD><TD><a href=\"ec.php?Ext=" .$row["Ext"] . "&Checkin=" . $row["Checkin"] . "&Checkout=" . $row["Checkout"] ."\">".$SecLab29."</a></TD></TR>\n" ;
    }
echo "</TABLE>\n";
endif;
```